# Kibana nano seconds showing zeros

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7, efk

Kibana not showing nano seconds, it is showing zeros
[image]

Actually timestamp is available in nano seconds

[image]

How to sort the data in kibana using nano seconds precision

Answer (score 0):

`date` data type stores dates in millisecond resolution. The `date_nanos` data type stores dates in nanosecond resolution, which limits its range of dates from roughly 1970 to 2262, as dates are still stored as a long representing nanoseconds since the epoch.

Queries on nanoseconds are internally converted to range queries on this long representation, and the result of aggregations and stored fields is converted back to a string depending on the date format that is associated with the field.

Date formats can be customized, but if no `format` is specified then it uses the default. As an example, You can customise the `date` field like this:

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "date": {
        "type": "date_nanos" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```